# Is there Facebook search box component?

Tags: facebook

I would like to use exactly same search box in my app, (to search ppl and saw her profile picture). Is there any good example how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do you mean something like...
http://www.9lessons.info/2009/06/autosuggestion-with-jquery-ajax-and-php.html

This guy has a lot of facebook examples.